# What is xterm's --enable-double-buffer configure option?

Tags: x11, xterm, configure

When running xterm's `./configure --help` there is an option

```
--enable-double-buffer  enable double-buffering
```

I've searched the web and came across the [X11 Double Buffer Extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXext/dbelib.html), the Introduction of which reads

> The Double Buffer Extension (DBE) provides a standard way to utilize
>   double-buffering within the framework of the X Window System.
>   Double-buffering uses two buffers, called front and back, which hold
>   images. The front buffer is visible to the user; the back buffer is
>   not. Successive frames of an animation are rendered into the back
>   buffer while the previously rendered frame is displayed in the front
>   buffer. When a new frame is ready, the back and front buffers swap
>   roles, making the new frame visible. Ideally, this exchange appears to
>   happen instantaneously to the user and with no visual artifacts. Thus,
>   only completely rendered images are presented to the user, and they
>   remain visible during the entire time it takes to render a new frame.
>   The result is a flicker-free animation.

Why would I want xterm to use double buffering? Usually an xterm doesn't need to update frames in short succession. Is there a benefit using this option for xterm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This option was added to address `xterm` flickering (on some setups) when resizing/scrolling back/long outputs.
The initial patch was [posted by a user on Archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146023). It was later integrated into `xterm` [source code](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282).